# vim creating imaps that do not cause other imaps to be executed

Tags: vim

I'm writing a basic plugin for a language and it would be really neat to have some special "words" `\` appear as `λ`.

But I have a problem.
I right now have:
`imap <buffer> \ λ`

But I also want to have:
`imap <buffer> \\ \`
In order to just write a `\`

Now the problem now is that when I type `\\` this gets replaced with a `\` that then gets turned into a `λ`.

How do I create mappings such that the don't "trigger" eachoter?

**Note:**

When I'm converting from fancy source to normal source and back I can easily distinguish between `\`that are supposed to be `λ` and those that should just be normal `\` since i know that each `λ` must eventually be followed by a `(` to  be an actual lambda.

Comment: You should take a look at `:help conceal`.

Comment: if you don't want to have remap, use inoremap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `inoremap` instead of `imap`, especially for your second mapping:

```
inoremap <buffer> \\ \
```

It was exactly designed for your problem : it prevents vim to use previously defined mappings inside another mapping.

Actually it's a good pratice to use almost always the `*noremap` version of mapping commands, because they prevent this kind of problem (which is not wanted in most cases). It's especially true when writing a plugin intended to be used by many people.